# Store special data on failed authentication

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-signals, django-contrib

I write simple Django project and I want to store client IP and date whenever a login attempt fails. I prepare model:

```
class FailIp(models.Model):

    ip = models.CharField(
        max_length=16,
        verbose_name=_(u'fail login ip'),
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

But I do not know how to hook up to the login error. Urls:

```
url(
    r'^login/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {
        'template_name': 'login.html'
    },
    name='login'
),
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good use case for [`django.contrib.auth.signals.user_login_failed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_login_failed) signal - was introduced in Django 1.5, it is sent when the user failed to login successfully:

```
from django.contrib.auth import signals

def listener_login_failed(sender, credentials, **kwargs):
    # handle log in failure

signals.user_login_failed.connect(listener_login_failed)
```

Also see [tests for `django.contrib.auth.signals`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/cd914e31c9a889f18c50c15b4f6ee4959624001f/django/contrib/auth/tests/test_signals.py).